# MPIO Disk active path

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I was using the below mentioned VBScript to collect the MPIO Disk active path information from multiple servers. I was trying to convert the VBScript to a PowerShell module, but am unable to find the appropriate class or get the values as expected.

```vb
Dim oFSO, oTSIn, oTSOut
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oTSOut = oFSO.CreateTextFile("results.txt")
Set oTSIn = oFSO.OpenTextFile("servers.txt")

Do Until oTSIn.AtEndOfStream
    sServerName = oTSIn.ReadLine
    intFreeSpace6=sServerName
    oTSOut.WriteLine intFreeSpace6

    On Error Resume Next
    Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
    Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20

    Dim wmi
    Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://" + sServerName + "/root/WMI")

    Dim mpio_disks
    Set mpio_disks = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MPIO_DISK_INFO")

    For Each disk In mpio_disks
        Dim mpio_drives
        mpio_drives = disk.DriveInfo

        For Each drive In mpio_drives
            Dim name
            name = drive.Name

            Dim paths
            paths = drive.NumberPaths

            Dim space
            space="= "

            oTSOut.WriteLine name & space & paths

            'WScript.Echo  name & paths 
        Next
    Next
Loop

oTSIn.Close
oTSOut.Close
MsgBox "Finished!"
```

PowerShell command tried is below but not able to get the path information:

```psh
$MPIODisks = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\wmi" -Class mpio_disk_info -ComputerName "$Server" |
             Select-Object "DriveInfo"

Write-Host "Host Name : " $Server

foreach ($Disk in $MPIODisks) {
    $mpiodrives = $disk.DriveInfo

    foreach ($Drive in $mpiodrives) {
        Write-Host "Drive : " $Drive.Name
        Write-Host "Path : " $Drive.Numberpath
    }
}
```

It is giving output as mentioned below:

```
Drive :  MPIO Disk0
Path :
Drive :  MPIO Disk1
Path :
Drive :  MPIO Disk2
Path :
Drive :  MPIO Disk3
Path :
Drive :  MPIO Disk4
Path :
Drive :  MPIO Disk6
Path :
Drive :  MPIO Disk7
Path :
Drive :  MPIO Disk8
Path :
Drive :  MPIO Disk10
Path :
```

Comment: Tried using  root\wmi -Class mpio_path_information but it is not able to show the paths per disk.. other than giving the total number of paths...

Comment: `Get-WmiObject : Invalid class "mpio_disk_info"` on Windows 8.1 Pro, I'll try on Windows Server ... same behavior on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Depending on OS version, there is a dedicated PS Module http://blogs.msdn.com/b/san/archive/2012/07/20/managing-mpio-with-windows-powershell-on-windows-server-2012.aspx + https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826113%28v=wps.630%29.aspx

Comment: This may be just a typo in your question, but the [`MPIO_PATH_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562446%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property you're trying to display is `NumberPaths` (with a trailing `s`), not `NumberPath` (without `s`). You have it right in your VBScript code, but not in your PowerShell code, and by default PowerShell doesn't throw an error when you try to access a property that doesn't exist. It just returns `$null`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers that's actually [MPIO_DRIVE_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562378(v=vs.85).aspx), but your point with missing "s" stands. Works fine for me on 2012 R2.

Comment: @sodawillow I believe MPIO is only available on Windows Server (and the `Multipath-IO` feature needs to be enabled).

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class mpio_disk_info).driveinfo | 
    foreach-object {
        "Name: $($_.name) Paths: $($_.numberpaths)"
}
```

Comment: need to add _ to $ enclosed in parenthesis: (gwmi -Namespace root\wmi -Class mpio_disk_info).driveinfo | % {Write-host "Name: $($_.name) Paths: $($_.numberpaths)"} @wonderer